# Python - using tuples as list indices

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
tuples_list = [(1,0), (2,3), (3,2), (2,0)]
```

And I would like to access the elements of a 2-dimensional array `a` using some of these tuples, for example

```
for i in range(3):
    print a[tuples_list[i]]
```

which should output the values of `a[1][0], a[2][3], a[3][2]`.
Just to clarify, `a` is something like

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24]]
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: You can't. You can use `a[tuples_list[i][0]][tuples_list[i][1]]` though. Or assign those two values to variables first with `for i1, i2 in tuples_list[:3]:`, then `print a[i1][i2]`. Or use `reduce(lambda l, idx: l[idx], tuples_list[i], a)` if you are feeling adventurous.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: there was, gone.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to accomplish that is to use tuple unpacking in the for loop, like so:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24]]
tuples_list = [(1,0), (2,3), (3,2), (2,0)]
for x,y in tuples_list:
    print a[x][y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split tuple into two variables using tuple unpacking:

```
>>> tuples_list = [(1,0), (2,3), (3,2), (2,0)]
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16], [17,18,19,20], [21,22,23,24]]
>>> for indexes in tuples_list:
...     i, j = indexes  # tuple unpacking
...     print a[i][j]
...
5
12
15
9

>>> for i, j in tuples_list:  # tuple unpacking
...     print a[i][j]
...
5
12
15
9
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
for i in range(len(tuples_list)):
    list_index, element_index = tuples_list[i]
    print(a[list_index][element_index])
```