# List of lists TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

Here is my list of lists and I'm trying to print a certain element:

```
boxes_preds = [[1, 300, 400, 250, 350],[0, 450, 150, 500, 420]]
print(boxes_preds[..., 0:1])
```

I get a

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect, use following syntax to get the elements inside list:
`list_name[index_of_outer_list_item][index_of_inner_list_item]`
so by that if you want let's say 300 of 1st list inside the outer list:

```
boxes_preds[0][1]
```

this should do it.

Comment: Illustrative pattern for indexing 2D arrays or lists - nice cheatsheet ️

Answer (score 1):

#### Indexing multi-dimensional lists

You can imagine the index as 2D coordinates written in form `[y][x]`.
Like when the nested lists represent a 2D matrix:

```
y / x
  | 1, 300, 400, 250, 350
  | 0, 450, 150, 500, 420
```

Where `x` and `y` both must be integers or in slice-notation:

```py
boxes_preds = [[1, 300, 400, 250, 350],[0, 450, 150, 500, 420]]

print(boxes_preds[0][0])  # integer index for both
# 1
print(boxes_preds[-1][0:2])  # last of outer list, slice index for inner
# [0, 450]
```

#### Using a tuple to index a nested list

There is a way to use tuples to index. As data-structure to store a 2D-index, but not as tuple inside the brackets:

```
coordinates_tuple = (1,1)  # define the tuple of coordinates (y,x)
y,x = coordinates_tuple  # unpack the tuple to distinct variables
print(boxes_preds[y][x])  # use those in separate indices
# 450
```

See [Python - using tuples as list indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361743/python-using-tuples-as-list-indices).

#### Ellipsis `...`

The [ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) (three dots) is a special syntax element used in *Numpy* or as output representation in Python.

However it is not allowed as list-index. Following example demonstrates the error:

```py
boxes_preds = [[1, 300, 400, 250, 350],[0, 450, 150, 500, 420]]
print(boxes_preds[...])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ellipsis
```

See:

- Python Land Blog: [Python Ellipsis (triple dots): What is it, How to Use](https://python.land/python-ellipsis)
- [How do you use the ellipsis slicing syntax in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python#118508)

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this:

```
boxes_preds = [[1, 300, 400, 250, 350],[0, 450, 150, 500, 420]]
print(boxes_preds[0][0:1])
```

`boxes_preds[0]` returns the first list in the `boxes_preds`, and then you use your slicing / index to access the elements of that list.

You would do the same to access later elements of `boxes_preds`, such as `boxes_preds[1]` to access the second list.

Comment: I got an error testing this: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ellipsis`

Comment: The ellipsis are supposed to be any value, not to be taken literally.

Comment: If you can explain the supposition to the Python interpreter, we can make your code work ️